# Is there a way to get the raw SOAP request from a SOAP based Web Service in a Java application

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am working on an application, that will pass client input to a vendor using web services. As phase I of the project, the vendor provided us with the XSD's and WSDL information. I used apache CXF to build the client jar. Now the issue I am facing is that, as part of the requirement, I need to send them the SOAP Request in an encrypted(I have taken care of the encryption part) XML file, that they  will manually process, and send me back the response in another XML file that I need to parse and retrieve the response object.

Is there anyway to use the client jar in a dummy mode or something, where it looks like we are calling the client, but all we are doing is getting the raw SOAP request to a file

I kind of a hit a dead end and I am not totally sure how to proceed here, any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: @Logan I will look into the SOAP UI, they have a way to mock service, I will need to figure out a way to do this automatically, like redirecting the request to a file or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try SoapUI, it's a free web service testing tool. I know you can view the raw data of your soap request and response with it. [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org)